# In the problem find the minimum value of $(a + b)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the problem a and b are positive real numbers , and two equations of $x^2 + ax + 2b = 0 $ and $x^2 + 2bx + a = 0$.Where  $a,b \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ has real roots. find the minimum value of $(a + b)$.

So far from discriminant property i have,

$a^2\geq8b\\
b^2\geq a\\
a>0\\
b>0$

Comment: This is a nice little problem in that it shows the 'fragility' of the minimum value with respect to the constraints. If you have $a\ge0, b\ge 0$, the minimum is $0$ instead of 6.

Comment: @copper.hat But in the question it is clearly given that $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: I understand that. I was making a pedagogical point, which is that finding minima or infimising values is often a delicate task. For example, it is not clear a priori that a minimum exists in the first place.

Comment: Uhm.. how do you even arrive at $ a^2 >= 8b$ What discriminant property? You have three variables...

Answer (score 3):

First, it should be $a^2\geq 8b$ and $b^2\geq a$.

Hint: From $a^2\geq 8b\geq 0$, deduce $a^4\geq 64b^2\geq64a$.

Comment: from ur hint , I arrived at $\left(\dfrac{a}{2\sqrt2}\right)^4> b^2>a$ but i m still confused...

Comment: so $\Large a\geq 4\\\Large and\\ \Large b\geq 2\\\Large  (a+b)_{min}=6 ?$

Comment: can u confirm that if my answer is correct ?

Comment: Well, $(a+b)_{\mathrm{min}}=6$ only if $a=4$ and $b=2$ is a valid pair. Is it? (Well, it is, but you have to verify it. Just knowing that $a\geq 4$ and $b\geq 2$ is not enough to assert this, however.)

Comment: ok, that need to be checked @thomas thanks for notifying that

Answer (score 2):

A diagram may help you.
[image]

You need to figure out which region is feasible.

The answer is:

> [image]

Comment: From the figure $(a+b)_{min} $ seems $0$. so should it be $0$.

Comment: No. The region should be **under** the purple curve and **above** the blue one.

Comment: So only the red and blue region is valid as in this [pic](http://prntscr.com/6ipgri)

Comment: No. The regions you colored is either under the purple curve **or** above the blue one. Neither satisfies the condition "under the purple curve **and** above the blue one".

Comment: ok so i hope u said the yellow region in this [pic](http://prntscr.com/6is8q0)

Comment: I really don't want to figure out the region myself, and I should have made my self clear enough. Maybe I have to add another graph.

Comment: ok so $(a+b)_{min}=6$.!?

Comment: Yes, that's the very answer.

Comment: $\quad$ Ok, thanks .